# Return result if indicator triggers during a time period or at the end of the period

Tags: pine-script

Right now, I use a custom indicator to generate a line whose value is 1 every 4 hours and 0 at all other times. I use that indicator to generate a buy alert to my bot every time the line crosses above 0.5.

```
study("Buy every 4 hours")
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])
plot(is_newbar("240") ? 1 : 0)
```

This divides up the day into 6 periods and 6 buys. Is there a way I can return a 1 prior to the period ending if say RSI crossed below 30, and if RSI doesn't cross below 30 to generate the 1 at the end of the period instead?

I essentially want a DCA strategy that would slightly accelerate the buys if another indicator shows an opportunity.

### Update

Thanks to PineCoders I was able to incorporate the second indicator into the signal, but I can't figure out how to get new_period to be equal to 0 if zscoreSignal had a 1 in the last period.

```
//@version=4
study("DCA buys")

buys_per_day = input(6) //number of buys to make per day
minutes_between_buys = 24 * 60 / buys_per_day

z_score_period = input(30) //period to calculate zscore from
xStdDev = stdev(close, z_score_period)
xMA = sma(close, z_score_period)
zscore = (close - xMA) / xStdDev

is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])
new_period = is_newbar(tostring(minutes_between_buys))

x = crossunder(zscore, -3.1)
var zscoreXdn = false
if new_period
    zscoreXdn := false
else if not zscoreXdn and x
    zscoreXdn := true
zscoreSignal = zscoreXdn and not zscoreXdn[1]

signal = new_period or zscoreSignal ? 1 : 0
plot(signal, "signal")
```

The red X's shows the signals that should not happen because of the preceding Z-Score signal during the period.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find and compare the distances from the moments of the last event `new_period` and `zscoreSignal` to the penultimate bar.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (DCA buys)")

buys_per_day = input(6) //number of buys to make per day
minutes_between_buys = 24 * 60 / buys_per_day

z_score_period = input(30) //period to calculate zscore from
xStdDev = stdev(close, z_score_period)
xMA = sma(close, z_score_period)
zscore = (close - xMA) / xStdDev

is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])
new_period = is_newbar(tostring(minutes_between_buys))

x = crossunder(zscore, 0) // for testing, I had to change the value for the script to work
var zscoreXdn = false
if new_period
    zscoreXdn := false
else if not zscoreXdn and x
    zscoreXdn := true
zscoreSignal = zscoreXdn and not zscoreXdn[1]

signal = (new_period and barssince(new_period[1]) < barssince(zscoreSignal[1])) or zscoreSignal  ? 1 : 0
plot(signal, "signal")
```

Comment: Thank you! Works exactly as intended! barssince was new to me!

Comment: There is a second solution to this problem without using a function `barssince`. For each event, you need to create a global variable and count the number of bars before the next event occurs. It requires more changes to the script, but there are cases that otherwise cannot.

Answer (score 1):

#### Version 1

Just add the RSI condition to your requirements. Note that with this code, you can get >1 signal in a 4-hour period when multiple crossunders occur between 4-hour events:

```
//@version=4
study("Buy every 4 hours")
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])
r = rsi(close, 14)
signal = is_newbar("240") or crossunder(r, 30) ? 1 : 0
plot(signal, "signal")

// For validation.
plot(r, "RSI")
hline(30)
plotchar(is_newbar("240"), "is_newbar(240)", "4", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(crossunder(r, 30), "crossunder(r, 30)", "X", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]

#### Version 2

This version only allows the RSI signal to occur once per 4H period:

```
//@version=4
study("Buy every 4 hours")
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])
new4HourPeriod = is_newbar("240")

// Trigger an RSI signal only once per period.
r = rsi(close, 14)
x = crossunder(r, 30)
var rsiXdn = false
if new4HourPeriod
    rsiXdn := false
else if not rsiXdn and x
    rsiXdn := true
rsiSignal = rsiXdn and not rsiXdn[1]

signal = new4HourPeriod or rsiSignal ? 1 : 0
plot(signal, "signal")

// For validation.
plot(r, "RSI")
hline(30)
plotchar(new4HourPeriod, "new4HourPeriod", "4", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(rsiXdn, "rsiXdn", "X", location.bottom, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(rsiSignal, "rsiSignal", "▼", location.bottom, size = size.tiny)
bgcolor(signal == 1 ? color.green : na)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it’s helpful. Is there a way I would be able to suppress the multiple signals? For every 4 hour period signal the first RSI crossover or if none occurred, signal at the end of the period no matter the RSI? My thinking is at each close, determine if RSI crossed over, if so check if another already happened since start time and if not, return signal. Would also have to determine if it’s an end time and if so, check if an RSI crossover occurred since start and if not, send signal.

Comment: Added a v2 that does that.

Comment: Thank you again. This is very close. I see where it is only signaling an RSI crossover just once in the period, but when an RSI crossover happens it is still signaling the end of the period. I am hoping it will skip the end period signal if an RSI crossover happens that way there are still only 6 signals in any 24 hour period. I took a screenshot of my original signal and your v2. The signals I'm hoping to skip have red X's in this image because they had an RSI crossover in the period. https://imgur.com/0uOw08K

Comment: I'll let you try things out for yourself. This isn't an indicator-writing service. You have enough logic and example code in there to get where you want on your own. If you have problems with your attempts to code the logic, post your attempts and perhaps someone will help.